# iPhone app crashing while navigating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i am developing a rss reader for iPhone, and i have a list of NSDictionary with the name of the site and the url. When i click the DetailDisclosureButton it takes me to another screen with the feeds of the site(I haven't implemented the xlm parser, so its just brings me the screen). Here's the problem after i go back and forth specifically 5 time my app crashes, and it does not show any message on the log.

I have no idea what is happening, what could cause such an error?

thanks!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
// Gets the site;
NSDictionary *site = [sites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// instantiate a view to see the unread news.
ViewUnreadController *uController = [[ViewUnreadController alloc] init];

uController.title = [site objectForKey:@"site"];
uController.site = site;

// adds the view to NavigationControllers stack (just adds a back button)
[self pushView:uController withBackTitle:@"Signatures"];

[site release];
[uController release];
```

And an additional information i am using the iPhone simulator 4.0.

Comment: What has caused the error is a bug in your application.  The correct resolution is to fix the bug, then your app won't crash anymore (assuming it's the only one).

Comment: The above "answer" may not seem very helpful, but it is about as specific as anybody can get unless you post the code that crashes, and perhaps the console log output including the error message and the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! I realized that i was releasing the "site" variable (without retaining it), since it was pointing to an object in a NSMutableArray the reference count reached zero!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you are over-releasing/under-retainig something. But without seeing you code, nobody will be able to tell more.

[NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) might give you some useful informations

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't really given us any information, so it could be a huge number of things. Profile your app, post the crash log here as an update to your question. Is this seen on the simulator or a device? Which device or what settings in the simulator are you using?

Arbitrarily guessing, maybe you're making new UIControllers and views every time and you're running out of memory. But that's just a shot in the dark at a target you haven't told me where is, or if it's even there.